# Programmatically Add a string custom option to a product in the cart?

Tags: cart, custom-options

I just would like to add a string as custom option so that it visible in the cart, when the product is rendered.

There is any straight way to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

Try using an observer `checkout_cart_product_add_after` and then add the options to  `additional_options` see [Magento - Quote/order product item attribute based on user input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9412074/magento-quote-order-product-item-attribute-based-on-user-input/9496266#9496266)